# bluetooth name change to default after a while

Tags: raspbian, bluetooth

I have three connected bluetooth dongles and I want to give each of these specific names.

I tested these solutions :

- add `PRETTY_HOSTNAME=MY_NAME` to `/etc/machine-info`
- edit `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf` and change `Name = MY_NAME`
- edit `/var/lib/bluetooth/XX:XX:XX:XX:XX/config` and change `name MY_NAME`

All these thing worked and the bluetooth dongle name changed ... but after a while (between 12 and 24 hours) the bluetooth name changed back to it's default: `CSR8510 A10`

How can I change the dongle's name permanently?